# Deleting records from a search result however not from the database

Tags: views, 7

I am trying to build a Candidate database site using Drupal 7.38 version

My Query: How do I save & delete certain search results from a search initiated however Not delete those results from the main database?

Eg. If I search for Manager in my database I would alos get General managers in the search result. How do I delete the general managers only from the search result & save Just the managers in a separate view?

I am not a developer, hence do not know a work around on this, please let me know any possible solutions to my issue.

Thanks for your help.